# Audit all insert, delete, update and select statements on a schema in Oracle 12.2

Tags: oracle-12c, audit

I cannot understand how to create a Unified Audit policy in order to audit all INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and SELECT statements performed on all the objects within a specific schema.

The goal is to track the tables and views involved in a specific PL/SQL procedure for a reverse engineering task.

For what I understood from the documentation, the only option is to specify each table/view to track within the policy. Is there an "audit all objects within a schema" construct for the create audit policy statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "audit all objects" setting. In unified auditing, do the following:

```
-- create the policy
create audit policy my_policy actions all on hr.regions;
alter audit policy my_policy actions all on hr.locations;
...

-- enable the policy
audit policy my_policy;
```

if you have a schema with a lot of tables, you can use SQL to build your script with something like this:

```
select 'alter audit policy hr_policy actions all on '||owner||'.'||table_name||';'
  from dba_tables
 where owner in ('HR','OE');
```

Answer (score 2):

You described traditional auditing. For unified auditing the parameter audit_trail has no meaning and is actually not considered by Oracle. As mentioned earlier, with unified auditing you have to create an audit policy.
Oracle does not write to SYS.AUD$ with unified auditing. It writes to audsys.aud$unified or spillover files on the OS (if the DB is not accessible). Your data is visible through the view unified_audit_trail, which selects from audsys.aud$unified and v$unified_audit_trail (spillover files).
To audit all insert,update,delete,select on a table scott.t1 you would use something like

```
create audit policy T1_AUDIT  
       ACTIONS select on scott.t1,  
               insert on scott.t1,  
               update on scott.t1,  
               delete on scott.t1;  
  
audit policy T1_AUDIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a policy is not necessary

```
AUDIT SELECT TABLE, UPDATE TABLE, INSERT TABLE, DELETE TABLE BY hr, oe;
```

will do the job

Comment: In unified auditing, creating a policy is necessary.

Comment: also, these commands are for actions committed _by_ hr and oe, not for actions on tables _owned by_ hr and oe.

Answer (score 0):

The following AUDIT statements are not limited only to 1 schema, but to all.

```
AUDIT ALL BY USER_NAME BY ACCESS;
AUDIT SELECT TABLE, UPDATE TABLE, INSERT TABLE, DELETE TABLE BY USER_NAME BY ACCESS;
AUDIT EXECUTE,PROCEDURE BY USER_NAME BY ACCESS;
```

Keep in mind that your audit_trail has to be set to DB,EXTENDED

Check your current audit_trail setting with:

```
SHOW PARAMETER AUDIT;
```

If it's not set to DB,EXTENDED   , you have to set it with:

```
alter system set audit_trail=db,extended scope=spfile;
```

In order the change of audit_trail take effect, you have to restart your DB instance.

You will find audit records in SYS.AUD$ afterwards.